# How can I interpret coefficients of quadratic and linear term?

Tags: regression, linear-model, regression-coefficients, quadratic-form

It may be a basic statistic question for someone, but I'm struggling with this.

I'm trying to interpret a regression analysis. 
Here is examples.

```
#example 1
a <- -0.100; b <- 15

x <- 30:100

y <- a*x^2 + b*x 
plot(x,y)
```

[image]

First example has negative quadratic coefficient and positive linear coefficient.

```
#example 2
a2 <- -0.100; b2 <- 10 

x <- 30:100

y <- a2 * x^2 + b2 * x 

plot(x,y)
```

[image]

Second example has negative quadratic coefficient and positive linear coefficient. But linear coefficient is smaller than first example.

My question is here. Both graphs have negative quadratic coefficient, so it made hump-shaped curve. However, I don't know how to explain the positive linear term. Linear coefficient in both graphs are positive, but overall curve shapes are different.

So, in that case, can I say "positive linear term can makes overall linear increase or peak at the beginning of x"?

To understand this, I googled several times, but I couldn't get clear this.

Any advice, or criticism for my question are welcome!
Also, I would be appreciated if someone could recommend any book or literature to understand this kind of basic regression things.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not really statistical or on topic here. However, any quadratic with a non-zero curvature can be written as $y(x)=a(x-x_0)^2+c$, where $y'(x_0)=0$, i.e. you are just shifting the location of $x_0$ (and the value of $y(x_0)$).

Comment: It may help to think of the case where the magnitude of the coefficient is very small.  For example in the case where the relationship between x and y is *almost* a straight line, the quadratic coefficient will *almost* be zero.